# raspberry does not play any sound (Raspbian)

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I cannot get any sound out from my raspi.

I have another SD with XBian and XBMC running so HW problem is discarted.

this is my lsmod

```
pi@cacharro ~ $ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
snd_bcm2835            16165  0
snd_soc_bcm2708_i2s     5474  0
regmap_mmio             2806  1 snd_soc_bcm2708_i2s
snd_soc_core          131268  1 snd_soc_bcm2708_i2s
regmap_spi              1897  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm                81593  2 snd_bcm2835,snd_soc_core
snd_page_alloc          5156  1 snd_pcm
regmap_i2c              1645  1 snd_soc_core
snd_compress            8076  1 snd_soc_core
snd_seq                53769  0
snd_timer              20133  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
evdev                   9419  2
snd_seq_device          6473  1 snd_seq
leds_gpio               2059  0
led_class               3688  1 leds_gpio
snd                    61291  7        
snd_bcm2835,snd_soc_core,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_compress
```

I tried `speaker-test -t sine -f 600` , nothing sounds.
I tried with HDMI, with headphones and with both at the same time. Nothing.

alsa-utils is installed

I want to play midi using ZynSubAddFX.

Any clue ?? Any extra details that may be useful ??

Comment: Can you run `alsamixer` or `amixer cset numid=1 400` ? Just phasing out low volume option

Comment: numid=1,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=1,min=-10239,max=400,step=0
  : values=400
  | dBscale-min=-102.39dB,step=0.01dB,mute=1

speaker-test does Not sound after that (hdmi on, and speakers in the analig output)

Comment: I dont know if that is interesting or not but the changes I do in alsamixer dont change the ouput of amixer cset numid=1 400, the mute is always set to 1.
But in alsamixer Im able to move the bar up and down and set it to mute or not... weird...

Comment: So after you set the bar all the way up with alsamixer, can you play a sound (e.g. `aplay yourAudioFile.wav`) ? Any sound coming out ?

Comment: I used `amixer cset numid=3 1` to force audio through the jack and I can play wav files (using aplay) but zynaddsubfx is stil silent

Ive readed somewhere that some tv refuse to play mono audio through HDMI.. but I though the audio was stereo.. zynaddsubfx at least is stereo

Comment: but if you plug your headphones into the audio jack it's all good, just an HDMI stereo issue ?

Comment: no. zynadfsubfx is still silent

Comment: Does the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34596460/625087) help at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally bought a 1.34€ USB sound card, is not an ideal solution but I got quality audio and mic line for the same price :)